# Rotational Spectrum of a Diatomic Molecule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, rotational-dynamics, spectroscopy

The rotational energy levels of a diatomic molecule are given by $$E_l=\frac{\hbar^2}{2I}l(l+1)$$ where $l$ is an integer. If the molecule is a dipole it can emit or absorb electromagnetic radiation in the form of photons by transitioning between these energy levels.

Now a photon has spin-one and so can add or take away a unit $\hbar$ of angular momentum. I'm trying to understand why this fact constrains all rotational energy level transitions to be between adjacent energy levels, i.e of the form $l \rightarrow l-1$ but not $l \rightarrow l-2$ etc.

If you look at the change in angular momentum of a single step transition (using the first case above), you have a difference $l(l+1)\hbar^2-l(l-1)\hbar^2=2l\hbar^2$ whereas if you use the second case you get $(l+1)(l+2)\hbar^2-l(l-1)\hbar^2=2(2l+1)\hbar^2$. I don't know if this is where I'm supposed to see it? Besides, in the first case, if the transition is to release a unit $\hbar$ of angular momentum, that means we must have $l=\frac{1}{2}$ which is clearly not true.

See page 151 (pdf page), second paragraph here:
http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JamesBinney/qb.pdf

Edit: I now believe that the book is asking me to believe (rather than actually be able to see just by looking at it) that because the photon adds or removes an amount $\hbar$, it can only make transitions between adjacent levels - I think the actual proof is probably quite complicated (or beyond the level of the section in the book) and involves selection rules. If anybody does have a simple way of seeing this though, please let me know :)